# how to detect user press right arrow key from cmd(.bat) or powershell and make if-else

Tags: powershell, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

*if user press "right arrow key"* i need to go to next page.
*if press "left arrow key"* how can i detect if anyone pressing arrow keys and navigate them.

Example:

```
(if right arrow pressed code here)
goto :2
(if left arrow pressed code here)
 goto :1
(if right arrow pressed code here)
 goto :2
(if right arrow pressed code here)
 goto :3
```

Comment: https://powershell.one/tricks/input-devices/detect-key-press

Comment: Answered on SO see [batch file - How can I accept arrow key presses from user input? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553934/how-can-i-accept-arrow-key-presses-from-user-input)